# GDB pretty printing ImportError: No module named 'printers'

Tags: python, c++, stl, gdb, pretty-print

I'm trying to add [pretty printing](https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/STLSupport) for STL in my GDB on Ubuntu 14.04. Some details on the tools:

OS: Ubuntu 14.04

gdb version:  7.7

python version: 2.7.6

python3 version: 3.4.0

But after I setup exactly as what the instruction said. I still get the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
  File "/home/jerry/myLib/gdb_stl_support/python/libstdcxx/v6/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from printers import register_libstdcxx_printers
ImportError: No module named 'printers'
/home/jerry/.gdbinit:6: Error in sourced command file:
Error while executing Python code.
Reading symbols from main...done.
```

Then I haved double checked my pretty printing installation directory. Under the directory `/home/jerry/myLib/gdb_stl_support/python/libstdcxx/v6/`, I can clearly see I have the printers.py file. And I also view the content of printers.py, I'm sure it also has the `register_libstdcxx_printers` class. Why the python interpreter is still complaining the `printers` module is missing? This seems really strange to me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just tried something myself, and luckily, now it's working. At least it can print out the map and vector content as expected. Here is what I did:

Since it's complaining that it can't find the `printer.py` module, then I think should probably I tell python interpreter where this file is located. So I first added this extra line to my ~/.gdbinit:
`sys.path.append("/home/jerry/myLib/gdb_stl_support/python/libstdcxx/v6")`

(After the line `sys.path.insert(0, '/home/jerry/myLib/gdb_stl_support/python')` )

Then running gdb again, I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
  File "/home/jerry/myLib/gdb_stl_support/python/libstdcxx/v6/printers.py", line 1247, in register_libstdcxx_printers
    gdb.printing.register_pretty_printer(obj, libstdcxx_printer)
  File "/usr/share/gdb/python/gdb/printing.py", line 146, in register_pretty_printer
    printer.name)
RuntimeError: pretty-printer already registered: libstdc++-v6
/home/jerry/.gdbinit:7: Error in sourced command file:
Error while executing Python code.
```

Given the error information, I edited the ~/.gdbinit file and commented the line `register_libstdcxx_printers (None)`.

And then after running gdb, it works.

But I'm still wondering if directory in sys.path is searched recursively? I mean in my mind, the python interpreter should work like this: once you have added one directory to `sys.path`, then the subdirectory under that directory will also get searched for a module file.

Comment: No, there is no "search" for module files. If a directory in sys.path contains other directories, these must be *packages* for you to be able to import modules from within. But then you need to give the package-name in the import statement. E.g. "import gdb" works, and "import gdb.printing" works, but *not* "import printing".

Comment: @deets Thank you for mentioning the _[packages](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages)_ concepts in python. I don't know python is organizing submodules like this.

Comment: Editionally I needed to edit ``python/libstdcxx/v6/__init__.py`` and replace ``from printers import register_libstdcxx_printers`` with ``from .printers import register_libstdcxx_printers`` (My GDB includes Python 3.4)