# GDB pretty printing: Python Exception <type 'exceptions.LookupError'> no codec search functions registered: can't find encoding

Tags: python, gdb, codec, pretty-print, gdbinit

I tried to setup pretty-printing with gdb for STL from :
http://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/trunk/libstdc++-v3/ and ran it according to the instructions

and fixed the issues of python as per the instructions at:
[GDB pretty printing ImportError: No module named 'printers'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26205564/gdb-pretty-printing-importerror-no-module-named-printers)

Now there is no error while sourcing the `gdbinit file`.

but I am stuck with the following `error`, while trying to print a multiMap:

(gdb) p mymMap

```
Python Exception <type 'exceptions.LookupError'> no codec search functions registered: can't find encoding:

Python Exception <type 'exceptions.LookupError'> no codec search functions registered: can't find encoding:
```

$1 =

Any hints on how to solve this?

1) Have tried adding import codecs before following stmt in gdbinit:

```
from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers
```

2) codecs module exists in the python install

```
version info:
gdb version - 7.5.1; 
python in gdb - 2.6.5
```

Comment: Use `set python print-stack full` and try again.  Then see if the full stack trace provides more information.  To me it sounds like something is wrong with your Python installation.

Comment: thanks Tom; I just get the message that no codec search function registered. and I can import it from gdb prompt by calling python; so python install may be fine?

Comment: full text from command prompt:  Breakpoint 1, FUN1(xxx=8, LookupError: no codec search functions registered: can't find encoding
YYY=
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "XXXXXXXXXX/python/libstdcxx/v6/printers.py", line 687, in to_string
    ptr = self.val ['_M_dataplus']['_M_p']
LookupError: no codec search functions registered: can't find encoding
, createNewModel=1) at My_file:1629
1629                    string XXXXX = blah blah
(gdb) python
>import codecs
>print codecs.__file__
>/path/Python-2.6.5/lib/python2.6/codecs.pyc

Answer (score 1):

I am able to make it work. My application uses c++ and python both. Hence my environment always contain PYTHONHOME/PATH setting which was a different python version than the python used to install gdb.  I re-insalled gdb with the the exactly same python and it is working fine now. Thanks for the hint, Tom.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is just to highlight the comment of @Tom Tromey that suggests:

```
set python print-stack full
```

which is what is needed for GDB to print the full stack trace when exceptions are raised in GDB python pretty-printers such as:

```
Python Exception <class 'gdb.error'> No type named >.:
```

but without any information about where this was raised. With the configuration above, one would get something like this instead:

```
@0x7fffffff91f0: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.gdbprinters/eigen/printers.py", line 341, in lookup_function
    return pretty_printers_dict[function](val)
  File "/home/user/.gdbprinters/eigen/printers.py", line 313, in <lambda>
    pretty_printers_dict[re.compile('^Eigen::RefBase<.*>$')] = lambda val: EigenMatrixPrinter("Matrix", cast_eigen_block_to_matrix(val))
  File "/home/user/.gdbprinters/eigen/printers.py", line 306, in cast_eigen_block_to_matrix
    return val.cast(gdb.lookup_type(type[begin:end]))
gdb.error: No type named >.
{<Eigen::RefBase<Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Array<autodiff::detail::Real<1, double>, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> const, 0, Eigen::InnerStride<1> > >> = {<Eigen::MapBase<Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Array<autodiff::detail::Real<1, double>, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> const, 0, Eigen::InnerStride<1> >, 0>> = {<Eigen::ArrayBase<Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Array<autodiff::detail::Real<1, double>, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> const, 0, Eigen::InnerStride<1> > >> = {<Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Array<autodiff::detail::Real<1, double>, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> const, 0, Eigen::InnerStride<1> > >> = {<Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Array<autodiff::detail::Real<1, double>, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> const, 0, Eigen::InnerStride<1> >, 2>> = {<Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Array<autodiff::detail::Real<1, double>, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> const, 0, Eigen::InnerStride<1> >, 0>> = {<Eigen::EigenBase<Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Array<autodiff::detail::Real<1, double>, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> const, 0, Eigen::InnerStride<1> > >> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, m_data = 0x555555c76580, m_rows = {m_value = 28}, m_cols = {<No data fields>}}, m_stride = {m_outer = {<No data fields>}, m_inner = {<No data fields>}}}, m_object = Eigen::Array<autodiff::detail::Real<1, double>,0,1,ColMajor> (data ptr: 0x0) = {[0] = <error reading variable>
```