# Why isn't Eclipse using GDB's pretty printing?

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging, gdb

I am using Eclipse 4.4.2 on Ubuntu 14.04, and GDB 7.7.1. I am trying to inspect the contents of some C++ standard library containers in the Eclipse debugger.

What I have tried so far: following instructions [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#How_can_I_inspect_the_contents_of_STL_containers.3F), I ran the command

`svn co svn://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/trunk/libstdc++-v3/python`

Copying it into `/home/myusername/prettyprint`.

Then I copied this text into my .gdbinit:

```
python
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/myusername/prettyprint/python')
from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers
register_libstdcxx_printers (None)
end
```

When I ran `gdb`, I got this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
  File "/home/myusername/prettyprint/python/libstdcxx/v6/printers.py", line 1266, in register_libstdcxx_printers
    gdb.printing.register_pretty_printer(obj, libstdcxx_printer)
  File "/usr/myusername/gdb/python/gdb/printing.py", line 146, in register_pretty_printer
    printer.name)
RuntimeError: pretty-printer already registered: libstdc++-v6
```

I searched for help on this, and found that the second last line in the file (`register_libstdcxx_printers (None)`) was not necessary, so I removed it. Then, when I ran `gdb` and typed:

`info pretty-print`

I got this output, indicating that the backend was installed properly:

```
global pretty-printers:
  .*
    bound
  libstdc++-v6
    __gnu_cxx::_Slist_iterator
    __gnu_cxx::__7::_Slist_iterator
    __gnu_cxx::__7::__normal_iterator
    __gnu_cxx::__7::slist
    __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator
    __gnu_cxx::slist
    __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator
    std::_Deque_const_iterator
    std::_Deque_iterator
    std::_List_const_iterator
    std::_List_iterator
    std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator
    std::_Rb_tree_iterator
    std::__7::_Deque_const_iterator
    std::__7::_Deque_iterator
    std::__7::_List_const_iterator
    std::__7::_List_iterator
    std::__7::_Rb_tree_const_iterator
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
    std::__7::_Rb_tree_iterator
    std::__7::__cxx11::basic_string
    std::__7::basic_string
    std::__7::bitset
    std::__7::deque
    std::__7::forward_list
    std::__7::list
    std::__7::map
    std::__7::multimap
    std::__7::multiset
    std::__7::priority_queue
    std::__7::queue
    std::__7::set
    std::__7::shared_ptr
    std::__7::stack
    std::__7::tuple
    std::__7::unique_ptr
    std::__7::unordered_map
    std::__7::unordered_multimap
    std::__7::unordered_multiset
    std::__7::unordered_set
    std::__7::vector
    [... many more lines of output omitted]
```

For good measure, I added the following lines to `.gdbinit`:

```
set print pretty on
set print object on
set print static-members on
set print vtbl on
set print demangle on
set demangle-style gnu-v3
set print sevenbit-strings off
```

So I opened Eclipse and started debugging my application, only to find that the ugly print was still in effect:

[image: Debugger still using ugly print]

How can I fix this to use GDB's pretty print; is pretty print even installed?

Comment: Note: `gdb -nx` and `info pretty-print` does not produce any output.

Comment: Normally your distro should install everything properly.  That's what that error message really means -- your install was redundant.  `gdb -nx` isn't a sufficient test, because the pretty-printers are loaded on demand; in this case, when libstdc++.so is loaded by the inferior.  So you have to try that with `-nx`.  I don't know why Eclipse isn't working, it probably should.

Comment: @TomTromey I should note that I installed Eclipse as a download from the Eclipse Foundation website and not with my system's package manager. And could you explain a little more what I should do? Load the libstdc++.so file with gdb?

Comment: Eclipse shouldn't matter.  What matters is gdb.  One thing to try is to debug an ordinary C++ program with gdb -nx.  If pretty-printing works there, then the bug is somehow with Eclipse.  Otherwise it is with your gdb (or libstdc++ or ...) setup.

Comment: @TomTromey I've never used GDB before, but I got a rudimentary session running and was able to print the contents of an `std::vector` after it was initialized: `$3 = {<std::__1::__vector_base<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >> = {<std::__1::__vector_base_common<true>> = {<No data fields>}, __begin_ = 0x606010, 
    __end_ = 0x6060e0, 
    __end_cap_ = {<std::__1::__libcpp_compressed_pair_imp<int*, std::__1::allocator<int>, 2>> = {<std::__1::allocator<int>> = {<No data fields>}, 
        __first_ = 0x6060e0}, <No data fields>}}, <No data fields>}` So it would appear that the problem is with GDB.

Comment: @TomTromey After some more tinkering today I got gdb to work using the extra line in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26205564/gdb-pretty-printing-importerror-no-module-named-printers), and I had to install `libstdc++6-4.6-dbg`. However, it still produces the same results in Eclipse, and trying to print an `std::unordered_map` gave me this error message: `Python Exception <class 'gdb.error'> cannot resolve overloaded method `_M_before_begin': no arguments supplied: $1 = std::unordered_map with 2 elements`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985414/enable-pretty-printing-for-gdb-in-eclipse-cdt

Answer (score 4):

The values in your screenshot look like memory addresses, which leads me to believe you're trying to inspect a *pointer* to an instance of an STL type. AFAIK, the pretty printers won't automatically dereference pointers, but will pretty-print if you [add a watch expression](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fexpressions%2Fref-addwatch.htm) that deferences the pointer.

The additional `.gdbinit` lines you're using shouldn't be necessary; the following steps are all that should be required (for Eclipse Mars.1):

1. Download the pretty printers:

   ```
   svn co svn://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/trunk/libstdc++-v3/python
   ```
2. Create a `/home/<user>/.gdbinit` file with the following contents:

   ```
   python
   import sys
   sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/prettyprint/python')
   from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers
   end
   ```
3. In the GDB settings for Eclipse (Window->Preferences->C/C++->Debug->GDB), set the GDB command file path to the `.gdbinit` file you just created.
4. For any existing debug configurations (Run->Debug Configurations) which require pretty-printing, select the debug configuration, then set the GDB command file path on the Debugger tab.

You can verify that GDB is pretty-printing as follows (once the first two steps of the previous procedure have been completed):

1. Save the following code in a file named `test.cpp`:

   ```
   #include <map>
   int main() {
       std::map<char, int> first;
       first['a'] = 10;
       first['b'] = 20;
   }
   ```
2. Compile with g++:

   ```
   $ g++ -g -o test test.cpp
   ```
3. Run gdb:

   ```
   $ gdb test
   ```
4. Set a break point:

   ```
   (gdb) b test.cpp:5
   Breakpoint 1 at 0x40093f: file src/test.cpp, line 5.
   ```
5. Run the program:

   ```
   (gdb) run
   Starting program: /path/to/test
   ```
6. When the break point is hit, the gdb prompt will be displayed. Print the map with the following command:

   ```
   (gdb) p first
   ```

   If all is well, you should see the following output:

   ```
   $1 = std::map with 1 elements = {[97 'a'] = 10}
   ```

Comment: your forgetting the line `register_libstdcxx_printers (None)`  which comes before `end` in the `.gdbinit` file.